# How to create field before 1 day from field(Date)

Tags: sql-server, datetime, date-format, getdate

I have a field name `last_update`.

I need to create new field is yesterday of `last_update`.

How to create?

Comment: Hint:  `dateadd()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,LAST_UPDATE)
```

Comment: No problem ! :)